# Plotting only if values fall into specific range

Tags: r

I'm currently working with a dataset of datazones and various factors relating to them in R. I wish to plot certain values from the dataset on a plot, but only if the datazones fall within specific coordinates. I've currently got this code, but to no avail:

```
if (datazones2$lon >= -4.327355 && datazones2$lon <= 4.275699 
                && datazones2$lat >= 55.87163 && datazones2$lat <= 55.89725){
  plot(datazones2$distance, datazones2$AverageMortalityRates.2014,
                             ylab = "Average Relative Mortality 2014-2017", xlab= "distance", main=heading)
 lines(datazones2$distance, datazones2$AverageMortalityRates.2014, type="b")
}
```

I thought a simple if statement would work, but I'm new to R. Any help on how to get it to plot within these conditions?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but with the values from the if statement? Or should I keep the if statement too?

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but this should work.

```
GoodPoints = which(datazones2$lon >= -4.327355 && datazones2$lon <= 4.275699 &&
                datazones2$lat >= 55.87163 && datazones2$lat <= 55.89725)
plot(datazones2$distance[GoodPoints], datazones2$AverageMortalityRates.2014[GoodPoints],
                ylab = "Average Relative Mortality 2014-2017", xlab= "distance", main=heading)
 lines(datazones2$distance[GoodPoints], datazones2$AverageMortalityRates.2014[GoodPoints], 
 type="b")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can subset the data and plot.  Note that `&&` returns only a TRUE/FALSE output of length 1

```
i1 <- with(datazones2, lon >= -4.327355 & lon <= 4.275699 & 
          lat >= 55.87163 &lat <= 55.89725)
d1 <- datazones2[i1,]
plot(d1$distance, d1$AverageMortalityRates.2014,
                         ylab = "Average Relative Mortality 2014-2017",
            xlab= "distance", main=heading)
lines(d1$distance, d1$AverageMortalityRates.2014, type="b")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for condition in 'if' statement but not subsetting the df later. You can bypass the if statement by subsetting the df. The code is as below.

```r
Filtered_DF <- datazones[datazones2$lon >= -4.327355 & datazones2$lon <= 4.275699 
                         & datazones2$lat >= 55.87163 & datazones2$lat <= 55.89725,]
plot(Filtered_DF$distance, Filtered_DF$AverageMortalityRates.2014,
     ylab = "Average Relative Mortality 2014-2017", xlab= "distance", main=heading)
lines(Filtered_DF$distance, Filtered_DF$AverageMortalityRates.2014, type="b")
```

Comment: @MurrayRoss Great! I have done a small edit in the suggestion. May be not needed since it is already working for you.